# how do you plot 3 similar data sets on the same graph in different colors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab-figure

How do I plot the following data in the same figure using MATLAB?

[image]

Frequency is measured in Hertz (Hz) and should be horizontal axis.
Fall Time is measured in microseconds (us) and should be vertical axis.

freq1 goes with falltime1
freq2 goes with falltime2
freq3 goes with falltime3

They should all be in different colors and the graph should have a legend.

How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hold on` command is probably what you want.

```
figure
hold on
plot(freq1, falltime1, 'r-o') % plot in red, circles connected with lines
plot(freq2, falltime2, 'g-o') % plot in green, circles connected with lines
plot(freq3, falltime3, 'b-o') % plot in blue, circles connected with lines
legend('1', '2', '3') % legend text
xlabel('Hertz (Hz)')
ylabel('Fall Time (\mus)')
```

[image: plot of three data sets on the same figure]